# Center div in IE5.x?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-6

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1>Sed sollicitudin dignissim justo, sed.</h1></div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
div#container
{
    text-align:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This creates a div `container` which spans across the whole screen, and another div `header` within the first div `container`, where the second div has a fixed width and is centered in the first div.

This works fine in IE6 but in IE5.x, it doesn't seem to center, it is aligned to the left of the screen.

How do I center this in IE5.x?

Comment: Why do you need to support IE5.x?

Comment: I know it doesn't help, but it is pertinent - why are you using IE5?

Comment: IE5 is a browser released in 1999. **1999**, thats 13 years ago

Comment: Here the technology are changing rapidly and we are in era of CSS3 and HTML5 still you are validating test in IE5 even Microsoft also not providing any patches or updated to this browser and also Microsoft says in website please update to IE7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE 5.x centres blocks as if there were inline elements.

```
#containers_parent { text-align: center; }
#container { text-align: left; } /* To reset the alignment for the text inside */
```

Comment: I think `text-align: center` should be on the parent of `#container`, not `#container` itself.

Comment: This is useful stuff - thanks. I just came across this and was annoyed at some of the comments to the OP. Sometimes we have to support legacy web applications (like corporate Document Management Systems, ERP etc.) where we do not have the luxury of changing the DTD. We have to work with what we have. If someone is asking how to repair a radiator hose on a model T Ford, telling them they should be working on modern cars is not helpful and a little bit ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

if the only thing you have on the page is #container just add `<center>` at the top